# Returning two values immediately surrounding a test value in an IEnumerable<float>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an `IEnumerable<float>` containing distinct values found in a three dimensional array.

Given a test value, I want to take two elements from my distinct `IEnumerable`, the closest value which is greater than or equal to the test value, and the closest value which is less than the test.

In other words, if my test value is 80.5, and my list contains:

- 1.0
- 1.65
- 2.345
- 99.439

Then I want an `IEnumerable<float>` or a `Tuple<float,float>` back which contains 2.345 and 99.439.

Is there a LINQ statement or combination of such which will do that? An approach without LINQ?

Comment: is the input `IEnumerable<float>` sorted?

Comment: Not necessarily, though I know it's not hard to put an `OrderBy(item => item)` onto it. I don't need the positions of the values, just the two values around my test.

Comment: What would the output be if the _exact_ value is in the list?

Comment: It would be the test value, and closest lesser value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using LINQ and assuming that there are only values > 0 in an input collection. There's no need to sort the collection first.

```
public Tuple<float, float> GetClosestValues(IEnumerable<float> values, float target)
{
    float lower = 0;
    float upper = Single.MaxValue;
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        if (v < target && v > lower) lower = v;
        if (v > target && v < upper) upper = v;
    }

    return Tuple.Create(lower, upper);
}
```

Comment: If all values are greater than zero that upper will never change

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, then the values in the list don't even have to be run through `Distinct` in order for this to work correctly, right?

Comment: This is by far the fastest based on the timing tests I'm doing today, which is a surprising result to me.

Comment: @RobPerkins - makes sense to me - it's one pass instead of two or more for most other solutions.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek, my thanks to you. This is simpler to read and faster than a parallelized LINQ query.

Comment: @RobPerkins Athough it does not answer your question about existence of a LINQ statement, I'm glad you have not gone crazy about LINQ and used a reasonable (and in my opinion more readable) solution.

Comment: There is irony; I ended up using an algorithm that doesn't require it! But, a question like this belongs on the SO site. Maybe I should post the timings as comments under each correct solution... (after further inspection, this and the `Aggregate` approach were similar in timing. All the others were slower.)

Comment: @RobPerkins You can and you don't have to :) Whoever will seek help from this question will likely also test it or will not be interested at all.

Answer (score 2):

In a tuple:

```
var t = Tuple.Create(list.Where(x => x <= value).Max(),
                     list.Where(x => x >= value).Min()
                    );
```

Although you don't state what the output should be if the value is *in* the list - in this case it would be a tuple with the same value for both "nodes"

Answer (score 2):

```
Tuple.Create(
    values.OrderBy(i => i)
          .SkipWhile(i => i < test)
          .FirstOrDefault(),
    values.OrderByDescending(i => i)
          .SkipWhile(i => i >= test)
          .FirstOrDefault());
```

1. Sort (ascending), skip all values less than `test`, take the first value greater than or equal to `test`.
2. Sort (descending), skip all values greater than or equal to `test`, take the first value less than `test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] data = { .1,5.34,3.0,5.6 };
double test = 4.0;

var result = data.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue), 
(minMax, x) => Tuple.Create(
    x < test && x > minMax.Item1 ? x : minMax.Item1,
    x >= test && x < minMax.Item2 ? x : minMax.Item2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is sorted (and few other assumptions on the requirements (such as what happens if there is a direct hit).

```
float prev=0;
foreach(float item in YourIEnumerableFloatVar)
{
   if (item > target)
   {
       return new Tuple<float, float> (prev, item);
   }

   prev = item;
}
```